# How do I control the height of a UITabBar selectedIndicatorImage

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I'm trying to style the `tabBar.selectedIndicatorImage` of my `UITabBar` and can't get it positioned correctly. It should be 50px tall and be aligned to the ***top*** of a given tab. However, it's aligned to the bottom:

[image]

```
class MenuTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      setTabs()

      styleTabBar()

    }
      func setTabs() {
    let tab1 = GradientNavigationController(rootViewController: FeedViewController())
    let tab2 = GradientNavigationController(rootViewController: NotificationsTableViewController())
    let tab3 = GradientNavigationController(rootViewController: SearchViewController())
    let tab4 = GradientNavigationController(rootViewController: CallsTableViewController())
    UITabBarController().setViewControllers([tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4], animated: false)
  }

    // UITabBarDelegate
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
      if item.tag == 0 { 
        if let feedNav = children[0] as? UINavigationController, let feedVC = feedNav.viewControllers[0] as? FeedViewController {
          feedVC.tableView.reloadData()
        }
      }
    }

    func styleTabBar() {
      // Set the tab bar separator
      UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(color:.white) //This sets the TabBar top separator color
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
      let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: 50)
      let selectionBackgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .lightGrey3, size: tabBarItemSize)
      selectionBackgroundImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), resizingMode: .tile)
      tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = selectionBackgroundImage
    }
}
```

UIImage extension:

```
  class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
    }
  }
```

The closest I've been able to come to even affecting the position of the image was by changing the origin of the `CGRect` in the `UIImage` extension:

`let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -25, width: size.width, height: size.height)`

[image]

but that just seems to reduce the height of the image which I need to keep at 50px.

I found a lot of threads about this on SO which is how I got even this far, but nothing I've found as worked in addressing this issue.

Comment: @matt, in my defense, I found that thread in my day long search but didn't consider it a duplicate because they are using a `UIImage` loaded from a file whereas I'm creating mine programmatically. Still, I tried making my image 49px high which, of course, didn't work. After a second reading today, I see that I needed to make it not 49px, but 48px. Thanks for forcing me to take another look.

Comment: I’ll mark this as an actual duplicate, then, so that we get another pointer to that answer. Thanks for reporting back!